# How to compare a query to a table in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have queries that finds people that are subscribed, and inserts their emails into a table. To update this, it always truncates the table and inserts all records in it again.
Now
I want this to not truncate and insert all the data each time (takes a long time for very large records), but do the selection and check with the old table if there was a change, and only add/remove those few records to the table.

Any Idea how would I approach this solution?

Comment: have a unique index on a column. Doing an `insert ignore` won't put it in again? Do an `insert on duplicate key update` perhaps? By the way, `insert ignore` is generally frowned upon.

Comment: An Example would be more helpful to understand your problem and to reach   best answer.

Comment: Recreating the table is probably faster.

Answer (score 0):

if not exists statement can check if the email exists and if not write a insert statement. below is a example hope it helps you :)
    if not exists(select * from t_emails where email=@yoursuscribeemail)
    begin
    insert into t_emails (email) values (@yoursuscribeemail)
    end
i am assuming the suscribe email is coming from the user end. if not comment

Comment: There is a column in customers (where you get the email addresses) table, if it has the value 1, that means they are subscribed, if it is 0, that means they have unsubscribed

Comment: share me the field of both the table.Will write you the statement

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from subscriber_emails
where email in (select email from subscriber_emails e
join users u on e.email=u.email
where u.subscribed=false);

insert into subscriber_emails (email)
select email from users u
outer join subscriber_emails e on u.email=e.email
where e.email is null;
```

Since I don't know the schema of your two tables I have to use some placeholders here, alter keywords as necessary.